# Swift any difference between Closures and First-Class Functions?

Tags: swift, closures, first-class-functions

In the Swift documentation Apple says this:

> Closures are self-contained blocks of functionality that can be passed
>   around and used in your code. Closures in Swift are similar to blocks
>   in C and Objective-C and to lambdas in other programming languages.

Which I thought was the definition of [First-class functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function)

And they also say this:

> Closures can capture and store references to any constants and
>   variables from the context in which they are defined. This is known as
>   closing over those constants and variables. Swift handles all of the
>   memory management of capturing for you.

I thought this was the definittion of closures while the other defitintion was for first-class functions, but Apple seems the put them together and call it closure.

Have I misunderstood something? or are Apple calling closures and first-class functions closures?

I've written this example code, and just wanna know if I'm right in the written comments?

```
// 'a' takes a first class function, which makes 'a' a higher order function
func a(ch: () -> Void){
    print("Something")
    ch()                // 'ch' is a first class function
    print("Ended")
}

func closureFunc(){
    var num = 2
    a({
        // access to 'num' is possible by closures
        num = num*2
        print(num)
    })
}

closureFunc()
```

Comment: Everything looks good - closures can grab parameters outside of them, including `self.` (has to be explicit). Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29022985/how-to-comprehend-the-first-class-function-in-swift?rq=1

Comment: If you feel your question has been satisfied, please accept one of the answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These notions are orthogonal. They are not directly related; they are two facts about functions in Swift.

- Functions are **first-class**. This means they can be passed around — assigned as variables, passed into function parameters as arguments, and passed out of functions as results.
- Functions are **closures**. This means that, at the point of definition, they capture the environment referred to *inside* the function body but declared *outside* the function body.

Here is an example (from a playground):

```
func multiplierMaker(i:Int) -> (Int) -> (Int) {
    func multiplier(ii:Int) -> (Int) {
        return ii*i
    }
    return multiplier
}
let g = multiplierMaker(10)
g(2) // 20
```

Think about the function `multiplier`:

- The fact that `multiplier` can be returned as the result of the function `multiplierMaker`, and assigned to `g`, and that it has a well-defined type `(Int) -> (Int)`, is because functions are *first-class*.
- The fact that, when 10 is passed into `multiplierMaker`, the resulting `multiplier` function multiplies its parameter by 10, even when assigned to `g` and called later, is because functions are *closures*.

(Notice that this has *nothing to do with anonymous functions*. All answers or statements leading you to believe that closures have to do with anonymous functions are wrong. There are no anonymous functions in this example. An anonymous function *is* a closure, but only because *all* functions are closures.)

Answer (score 9):

A **First Class Function** is a language feature that allows a function that can be assigned to a variable and passed around as if it were any other kind of data. Closures, lambdas and anonymous functions are all "First class functions".

**Anonymous Functions**, also called **Lambda** functions, are functions that don't have a name (such as the way `a(ch:)` has a name). Because they don't have a name, the only way to use them is by storing them in a variable or passing them in as arguments (parameters are essentially variables). Thus all Anonymous functions are also First Class Functions.

**Closures** are first class functions that capture the state around them. They can be anonymous, or have a name. Named closures are just your regular `func` functions.

`a(ch:)` is a higher order function, correct.

`ch` is a First Class Function (as it's stored in a variable), a Lambda (synonymous with FCF) and possibly also a closure, depending on whether or not its body references any external variables.

In the case of `a(ch:)` being called with that block, `ch` is a closure, because it's capturing `num`.

Comment: "Closures are anonymous functions" No. _All_ functions are closures in Swift.

Comment: This deserves to be the answer!

Answer (score 4):

Functions can capture variables in the context they were declared in, and "A combination of a function and an environment of captured variables is called - closure" [more](https://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/06/11/a-basic-tutorial-on-functions-and-closures-in-swift/)

Here is a simple explanation of closures and first class functions in Swift:

1. Functions are first class objects, they can be assigned to variables, they can be passed as arguments and can be returned
2. There are two ways of defining functions in Swift: one using the func keyword and using 'closure expressions' - (does not mean closures). e.g.

   ```
   func f() { print("nothing") }

   let a = f // cannot use parentheses here

   // or using closure expression:
   let a = { () -> void in print("nothing") }
   ```
3. And finally the direct answer to your question: Functions can capture variables in the context they were declared in, and "A combination of a function and an environment of captured variables is called - closure" e.g.

   ```
   func f() -> ()->()
   {
       var c = 0 // local var

       func innerf()
       {
           c += 1 // c is now captured 
       }

       return innerf
   } // normally c would be released here. but since its used in innerf(), it will stay

   let f1 = f
   ```

   Now we call f1  a closure because it captured a variable.